# GetElementById IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, getelementbyid

I have this:

> ```
> <input type="hidden" id="aid" value="<? echo $_GET['id']; ?>"></div>
> ```

and

> ```
>   var aID = document.getElementById('aid');
>   var postFile = 'showcomments.php?id='+ aID.value;
>   $.post(postFile, function(data){
> ```

Why will this only work in FF and not IE?

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of IE?
Type it in your post.

Comment: Doesn't work ***how***? (C'mon people, be specific!!)

Comment: which part fails ? Also close you input tag <input ... />

Comment: @Gaby: Only if he's using XHTML, which he didn't say he was and arguably most people don't.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, true .. but it is a good habit to get into regardless..

Comment: Its a very bad habit to get into if you aren't using XHTML.

Comment: Also the `echo` without escaping presents a XSS risk. Every string output into HTML must be passed through HTML-encoding (`htmlspecialchars` in PHP), every string inserted into a URL paremeter (`aID.value`) must be passed through URL-encoding (`encodeURIComponent` in JavaScript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE has issues (bugs) with keeping namespaces distinct. Do you have *anything* else on the page that uses "aid" as an `id`, a `name`, a variable at global scope, ...? If so, that's your problem. An easy way to check is to do an experiment: Change the hidden field's ID to `flibberdegibbet` and change the string in your `getElementById` call. If it starts working, that means you have a name conflict somewhere.

Comment: Excellent. Man, the time we spend on IE bugs.

Comment: I'm afraid now that the OP has just kept the code as flibberdegibbet and declared case closed!

Comment: So was the problem that more than one element on the page had the same value for `id` -- that is, `aid` ?

Comment: Yes i believe so, even though i couldn't find any other element that had the same id (aid). But it worked.